# Memory Leak using msxml3.dll

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

Currently on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard with 32GB memory.

Once the server hits a Memory usage of around 50% (18GB, 13GB of it is for SQL Server (2008)) some strange things are happening with the `XMLHTTP` requests.  I have tried using `"Microsoft.XMLHTTP` and `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` but i get the same result.

I am getting a 2 different errors all associated with the msxml3.dll file:

```
 Error #: -2146697211
 The system cannot locate the resource specified.
```

and

```
 Error #: -2147024888
 Not enough storage is available to process this command.
```

After i restart the server, everything seems to be working fine, for now at least, we'll see when the memory usage starts increasing.

I have searched a while for a solution, and have found that nothing seems to work except for restarting the server, haven't tried just restarting IIS, but I am wondering why this is happening all of a sudden.

Comment: Why are you using this COM object from T-SQL? Strongly recommend CLR instead (or simply not trying to hit web pages from inside SQL Server).

Comment: Hi Aaron, the script is in Classic ASP, it's not being exec from SQL, the ASP script is crashing when server hits high memory, mostly affiliated with SQL.

Comment: So you think that because SQL Server is taking 13GB of disk space that it must be related?

Comment: That's when it starts to happen.. idk what else to do.

Comment: This all started happening when i added a couple indexes to the DB and it started allocating more memory to the server, it may be related, or may be not, i am not experienced enough with this to know, but i do know that building the SQL indexes did somewhat trigger the issue.

Comment: I suggest showing your actual ASP code and taking sql server out of the tags. If your XMLHTTP requests are using up all available memory due to some kind of leak, it doesn't really matter whether it's being shared by SQL Server or something else. I assume you have `max server memory` set for SQL Server, right?

Comment: The ASP code is a simple HTTPRequest that works on every other server, and this one, just not when there is alot of mem being used, not sure how it would address the issue exactly, but the Max memory in SQL is 2147483647 MB, and min memory per query is 1024 kb

Comment: Just how big is the entity you are fetching with `ServerXMLHTTP` (which BTW is the correct one, don't use XMLHTTP)?  Is the AppPool configured as 64bit or 32bit?  How much mem do the W3WP.exe processes consume?  Have your tried a simple AppPool recycle?  Do you have a standing recycle policy in place?  Over what time period does the problem manifest itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean to reserve only 13GB of memory for SQL Server, you need to tell someone. Right now you've told SQL Server to take over the server if it wants.

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show adv', 1;
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'max server memory', 13000;
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
GO
```

Now restart SQL Server. This won't guarantee that SQL Server won't use more than 13 GB, since this setting only controls certain aspects of its memory usage, but it will prevent SQL Server from taking over the box.

This is the setting I assumed you had already set what you said:

> 18GB, 13GB of it is for SQL Server (2008)

Comment: There is 32GB on the server, and it has never gone over 18GB, i don't think i should be too worried with the max on SQL, because theres still alot of room left to hit 32GB, right?

Comment: Apparently not, if you're saying SQL Server is causing your MSXML component to go haywire with memory, and you're not bothering to cap SQL Server's memory -- something is not adding up here./

Comment: What does capping it do to the performance of SQL if it runs over 13GB?

Comment: Well I said 13GB when it sounded like you had 18GB total and 13GB allocated to SQL Server. So maybe 13GB is not your magic number, and you will need to experiment to find the sweet spot. You can read about the caps in Books Online http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180797.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177455.aspx.

Comment: An Object wasn't being closed.. Once i set it to nothing, error hasn't happened since, same stress levels.. I'm an idiot ;), i gave u best answer for sticking around.. Thanks again Aaron!